# Want ot count values in column when a differnet column value is fixed in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am having the following `dataset`:

```
Year  Y  Z
2018  A  1
2019  B  1
2019  A  1
2019  A  1
2019  A  1
2019  C  1
2020  A  1
```

Now I want to find the number `A` in the year 2019 alone using python. How do I find it?

Comment: Can you provide a clearer picture of what your dataframe looks like, in the format `pd.DataFrame({"column1":["value 1", "value 2"], "column2":["value 1", "value 2"]})`? Also, 2019 A occurs twice.

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use the following if df is the name of your dataframe :

```
sum(df[df['Year']==2019]['Y']==A)
```

return 3 for your example